# How can I preload my mp3 stream which is from a web link

Tags: ios, swift, web, mp3

I have my song playing from an mp3 website however I need to preload the song so that when I run player.play(), the song will start immediately with no buffering and also hopefully not buffer throughout the whole song. Is there a way to accomplish this or would the file have to be stored locally?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
    println(test_)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.02, target: self, selector: "saveTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    appDelegate.mpcHandler.sendSongInfo()

    NPMusicClient.sharedClient().urlForSongWithQuery("\(artistName_) \(title_)", success: { (url) -> Void in
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        self.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

        self.player.play()

        }) { (message) -> Void in
            println(message)
    }

    startplaying()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    println(boolValue)
    functionLevel()




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so I found an answer to my question by myself, simply put if anybody else is looking at accomplishing this, simply mute the player as the song will buffer as it is playing and then seek back to 0:00